# Remove login link from Reset Password-screen

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I haven't been able to find anything useful regarding removing or hiding the "Login" link from the Reset Password screen and the screen after succesfully choosing a new password.
I'm using a custom login-form made with GravityForms and would like to stay away from the built-in Wordpress forms as much as possible, but I can't make a custom reset. The built-in forms can work if I can remove the links to login, so the users aren't able to login any where else but the one I've made with GravityForms.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you wanting the link removed because you don't want users to login from there, or do you want it removed because it leads to `wp-login.php` and you need users to go through your custom login form? Because if it's the latter there's an easy solution that lets you keep the login link while using your custom login page and _only_ your custom login page

Comment: Hey @TomJNowell, it's both in the sense I don't want them to be able to see the admin panel - they are all subscribers, so they can't do much, but I don't want them to see their Wordpress profile.

Comment: then you can change the login URL and you can redirect users to the homepage if `is_admin()` is true. You should look up questions here asking how to change the login URL

Comment: Thanks Tom for pointing me in a direction :)

Comment: For anyone interested I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282064/hide-wp-login-php-as-log-in-and-redirect-it-to-a-custom-login-page#comment117049408_57277488) at Stackoverflow, which helped me. I used the answer from Maher Aldous with the small modification to the $page where I took the entire URL of the custom login page instead of URL from get_bloginfo.